# how to process/link subprocess popen with another popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this subprocess that I need to resume.

First `popen` is:

```py
try:
        j = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Program Files (x86)\python\python.exe",r"C:\Program Files (x86)\python\New folder\main\training\news-please-master\news-please-master\newsplease\__main__.py","-c newsplease/config"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell = True)
        return "0"
    except:
        return "1"
```

Second `popen` is:

```py
try:
        i = j.poll()
        if (i == None):
            k = subprocess.Popen(["python",r"__main__.py","-c newsplease/config","-resume"],stdin=j.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            return "0"
        else:
            return "1"     
    except:
        return "1"
```

these two popen are in different methods.I need to resume the first `popen` from the second `popen` because these are two different object but i need to resume the first object only. How to do this?

Comment: What do you mean you want to resume the first one? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: BTW the return value of `subprocessPopen` is the *handle* that allows to communicate with the subprocess. IMHO you should not discard that...